# Tensorflow: dlerror: cudnn64_8.dll not found but it appears to exist

Tags: python, tensorflow, dll

I know this seems to be a common question but I cant seem to find a thread specific to my issue.
I am running windows 10, with a gtx 1050.
I am trying to install tensorflow 2.5 according to this tutorial: https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#tf-install

I've installed CUDA 11.2 and CuDNN 8.1.0.

I've installed the correct CuDNN version and CUDA according to the tutorial and my computer settings, and I've checked that I have the cudnn64_8.dll in my cuda folder: D:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.2\cuda\bin

I'm running a python venv for tensorflow.

I've also made sure that the PATHS are updated, and I've also restarted my terminal and computer.
Im confused as to why the .dll file is unable to be found.

Comment: Please check and verify that you have followed all the instructions mentioned in [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu#windows_setup) link for successfull `windows setup` for `gpu support`. Let us know if issue still persists.